# Hover buttons in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create hover buttons in a Wordpress page. I do not wish to use jquery or javascript, simply using CSS.

I am able to create 1 button but when trying to position multiple buttons side by side with a hover text box it does not seem to work. Here is the code I am trying:

CSS

```
/* cat button and content */
.cat_content {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.cat_trigger:hover .cat_content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.cat_trigger:hover .ok {
display: inline-block;
}

/* dog button and content */
.dog_content {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.dog_trigger:hover .dog_content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.dog_trigger:hover .ok {
display: inline-block;
}

/* mouse button and content */
.mouse_content {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.mouse_trigger:hover .mouse_content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.mouse_trigger:hover .ok {
display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Cat Button -->
<div class="cat_trigger">
  <button>Cat</button>
  <div class="cat_content">Meow</div>
</div>

<!-- Dog Button -->
<div class="dog_trigger">
  <button>dog</button>
  <div class="dog_content">Woof</div>
</div>

<!-- Mouse Button -->
<div class="mouse_trigger">
  <button>mouse</button>
  <div class="mouse_content">Eee</div>
</div>
```

I am unable to align the buttons side by side and have a text box displayed below in the same spot. Can anyone think of how to do this? Or an easier way?

Comment: Can totally do this, but we'd need to understand what you want for a layout, first.  Can you do a screenshot / sketch of the desired layout?

Comment: Just to have buttons:
    Cat   Dog   Mouse
and when the user hovers over each, display the text below:
    Cat (hovered)
    Meow

Comment: I can get it this close: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mkaasd94/. The buttons are each on separate rows though.

Comment: button {
 display:inline;
}

Answer (score 0):

As I understand something like this is what you need

HTML

```
<!-- Cat Button -->
<div class="hover"><button>Cat</button>
<div class="show">Meow</div>
</div>

<!-- Dog Button -->
<div class="hover"><button>dog</button>
<div class="show">Woof</div>
</div>

<!-- Mouse Button -->
<div class="hover"><button>mouse</button>
<div class="show">Eee</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.show {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.hover:hover > .show {
  display: block;
}
```

fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/nhew8hxc/

Comment: That is closer, I tried to update the text to fall below the button, and the other buttons dropped down. Any way to anchor?

https://jsfiddle.net/nhew8hxc/2/

I am trying to almost get the effect of an in-page navigation bar with a text box below updated by the rollover.

Comment: not really sure what you mean, you can add negative bottom value on ```.show``` to move the text lower, e.g. ```bottom: -40px;``` maybe edit the fiddle and send me the updated link

Comment: I got mouse to display properly, but when I select the other buttons, it messes with the placement. https://jsfiddle.net/nhew8hxc/4/

Comment: absolute position for ```.show``` is required so the buttons won't be affected with the element ```.show``` position, you can use ```top```,```bottom```,```left```,```right``` property to move up, down, left or righ

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use that on a page in Wordpress, it filters it out.